# can't execute in break mode

Tags: excel

estoy tratando de correr el siguiente código

```
Workbooks("book2.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A8").Value = "D2"
```

y me dice:

> can't execute in break mode

¿Alguien sabe qué ocurre?

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Juan! te doy la bienvenida,  es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y además obtienes tu primera medalla. Además es **muy importante revisar [ask]** que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas, saludos y suerte!.

Answer (score -1):

Tal vez sería necesaria más información, un motivo por el que puede suceder es debido a que tienes **algun macro corriendo mientras tratas de hacer una depuración**.

Por ejemplo un macro que te realiza la tarea de autoguardado o que saque estadísticas de tu código podría interferir sin que el problema resida realmente  en en el código que estás realizando.

Comment: gracias! voy a revisar mi script a ver si hace falta algo.